# C++ shared_ptr based singletone what causes link error?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton, shared-ptr

So I try this code:

```
#ifndef TRANSMITTER_H
#define TRANSMITTER_H
class connector
{   
public:
    static boost::shared_ptr<connector> Instance(){
        if(!instance)
        {
            instance = boost::shared_ptr<connector>(new connector());
        }
        return instance;
    }
private:
    connector(){}
    static boost::shared_ptr<connector> instance;
};
#endif //TRANSMITTER_H
```

But get link error:

```
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class boost::shared_ptr<class connector> connector::instance" (?instance@connector@@0V?$shared_ptr@Vconnector@@@boost@@A)
```

What is wrong with shared_ptr I want to return? Shall I make it function scope static variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), specifically last item of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/635608

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This

```
static boost::shared_ptr<connector> instance;
```

inside your class definition is just a *declaration*. What you don't seem to have is a *definition* of it. This *definition* has be outside of the class definition.

However, you should probably prefer to do this:

```
class connector
{   
public:
    connector(connector const&) = delete;
    connector& operator=(connector const&) = delete;

    static boost::shared_ptr<connector> Instance()
    {
        static boost::shared_ptr<connector> instance (new connector);
        return instance;
    }
private:
    connector(){}
};
```

In this case `instance` is *defined* as a static function-local object inside your inline function definition of `Instance`. The nice thing about it is that this kind of initialization is guaranteed to be thread-safe in C++11.

Comment: This is a neat answer, especially the hint to thread-safetyness. What displeasures me is, that the presented singleton is copyable, isn't it? Is it possible to have both: a shared_ptr-singleton which is noncopyable?

Comment: @AquilaRapax: good point! Yes, i think this should be easily possible. I'd simply make the copy ctor private or turn it into a deleted function.

Answer (score 2):

You should define

```
boost::shared_ptr<connector> connector::instance;
```

in your *.cpp
This makes linker allocate the memory for this static member in static data area.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define static members outside of the class declaration. Here's what the definition looks like:

```
boost::shared_ptr<connector> connector::instance;
```

It should be in a cpp, for you probably transmitter.cpp